# C# this.Enqueue() strange behavior when using "temp" object data to enqueue

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm experiencing this behavior.  Consider this code

```
classQtData temp_data = new classData();  //consider this...

public int AddData(ref classSerialPort serial_com )
{
    int return_number_of_packet_read;
    int index_a;

    return_number_of_packet_read = 0;

    while (serial_com.GetRawData(ref raw_vector) > 0)
    {

        //assign temp__data stuffs....
        temp_data.rolling_counter = (uint)raw_vector[40];

        this.Enqueue(temp_data);
        return_number_of_packet_read++;
    }

    return return_number_of_packet_read;
}
```

In this case, if while loop is executed (say) 3 times, the same `temp_data` object (the last inserted) will be enqueued three times, instead of inserting 3 different objects.

This code snippet, otherwise, works as I expect, enqueuing the right elements:

```
public int AddData(ref classSerialPort serial_com )
{
    int return_number_of_packet_read;
    int index_a;

    return_number_of_packet_read = 0;

    while (serial_com.GetRawData(ref raw_vector) > 0)
    {
        classQtData temp_data = new classData();

        //assign temp__data stuffs....
        temp_data.rolling_counter = (uint)raw_vector[40];

        this.Enqueue(temp_data);
        return_number_of_packet_read++;
    }

    return return_number_of_packet_read;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the ref keyword is not needed in the method signature since your method never changes the serial_com reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is because you have added three identical references to the **same object**. There is only one `classData` in your first example, so it should not be surprising that you see the same object multiple times. Basically, the first example is simply wrong, and the second is right: in the second, you create a different object per iteration.

The value of `temp_data` is simply a reference to an object that lives somewhere else. When you `Enqueue(temp_data)`, you are just adding a copy of the *reference* to the queue - not a copy of the object. In human terms, that is like copying a street address: it doesn't matter how many copies of that street address you make: they all refer to the single building.

Comment: really helpful: I supposed that Enqueuing is not "by reference", but "by value". I still have lot to learn! Thank you again

Comment: @grazianogovernatori you need to be very precise when using terms like "by value". In this case, it is "passing a reference by value". No, really.

Comment: my expertise is in embedded C development, so I would say "pass the pointer to a variable", i think we're saying same thing.  Thanks again!

Comment: @grazianogovernatori except that isn't what it is doing: it is "passing a pointer" - nothing more. `temp_data` **is** a pointer - kind-of